# WIA's DeviceManager has 0 DriveInfos

Tags: c#, .net, wia

My WIA `Device Manager` semms to always have 0 `DeviceInfo` entries.
Here's my code:

```
DeviceManager m = new DeviceManager();
Console.WriteLine(m.DriveInfos.Count); // Always is 0 (Problem)
// Process Devices
for (int i = 1; (i <= m.DeviceInfos.Count); i++) // Assuming multiple scanners
{
    try
    {
        if (m.DeviceInfos[i].Type == WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType)
        {

            DeviceInfo di = m.DeviceInfos[i];
            string n = di.Properties["Name"].get_Value().ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("Scanner found: "+n);
            scanners.Add(di); //Add to list for later use
        }
    } catch { }
}
```

Is there an alternative to WIA or is there a fix for that problem?

Comment: If you are on a 64-bit system, is it possible that the bit-ness of your program doesn't match the bit-ness of the driver?

Comment: @ZevSpitz just checked. still doesn't work

Comment: Console.WriteLine() is fishy.  Try adding [STAThread] on the program's Main() entrypoint.

Comment: so does this only work on the main thread? i'm executing it from another Thread... i might try it a bit different